# Usage/Meaning of "in die Zange nehmen"

Tags: meaning, usage, meaning-in-context

I have found this used in another quote from the movie "Der Untergang" and the dialogue goes something like this...

> Wir halten die Stellung bis zum Letzten!
>
> "Und welche Stellung soll das sein? Das ist keine Stellung, das ist eine Falle! Die Russen nehmen euch in die Zange und ihr könnt nicht mal wegrennen!"

I actually kind of understand it idiomatically and it is an idiom. However, on Linguee this phrase shows up as "to heckle" which I'm 100% sure isn't what is going to happen in the next scene from the film.

So my question is, what is the true meaning and usage? I would like to be able to add this idiom to my vocabulary. Also, is it specific possibly region specific?

Comment: Everyone's answers and thoughts on this was amazing! You all make learning german so much fun!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### *jmdn. in die Zange nehmen*

This proverb goes back to the grip, plier or pincer (*Zange*) tool of a blacksmith used to hold the glowing iron while forging.

Some people also believe there was an analogy to medieval torture tools in addition but this may not have been the main source of this figurative meaning.

So whenever there is an often figurative meaning of holding somebody or a process thightly in a grip we may use *in die Zange nehmen*. This does not imply a military context in most cases but it always needs a forced action. This "force" does not need to be of physical nature but most often it will be emotional pressure (like e.g. in a cross examination).

[image]
<sub>*Er faßt ihn mit der Zange*</sub>
<sup>*dem Teufel wird es bange*</sup>
<sup>W.Busch: Schmied und Teufel</sup>

Derived from a military maneuver is the near identical English expression: [Pincer movement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pincer_movement).

Comment: Very awesome answer, I especially like the picture. A very nice touch. The only the I'm left wondering is when could I possibly say this aside from situations where someone is getting surrounded or cut off from something? I can think of some gaming or movie contexts of course.

Comment: @Autumn See edit - it is mostly used in a figurative meaning.

Answer (score 2):

It is actually a figurative expression. just picture yourself using pliers on an object: the business parts of the pliers will approach the object from the sides, as compared to anything approaching (or in this case, attacking) from the front. In a military context this means that you attack from the weaker sides, hoping to result in encircling the enemy completely.

Answer (score 2):

I think the origin of the phrase *in die Zange nehmen* is a military maneuver that's called pincer movement in English. The German word for it is "Zangenangriff". The enemy is attacked on both flanks. The own forces are moved in the shape of a pincer. See [English](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pincer_movement) or German Wikipedia.

I think in the film "Der Untergang" this phrase is used in this military context. But the phrase is also used figuratively. For example

> Der Kommissar nimmt den Verdächtigen in die Zange.

means that the police inspector questions the suspect very intensely. [Wiktionary](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/jemanden_in_die_Zange_nehmen) suggests *to grill somebody* as translation.

I think this phrase is not limited to a specific region in Germany.

Comment: It would be interesting so see what expression was used earlier in German *in die Zange nehmen* or *Zangenangriff/Zangenbewegung* to see which might be derived from which.

Comment: I find your example a bit weird however. *In die Zange nehmen* usually implies two (seldom more) seperate entities simultaniously closing in on their common target - reflecting the mental image / semantic aspect of the tool (pincer / prongs) it takes the name from. To me it sounds weird using *in die Zange nehmen* referring to a single actor/person (*Kommissar*). I think *in den Schwitzkasten nehmen* would fit better.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, given the military context,

> etw<sup>A</sup> in die Zange nehmen

means to *encircle something* by offensively mimicking the form of a *Zange*:
two units restricting movement of the target by actively engaging / closing in on it from different sides.

Comment: Forgive me for nitpicking, but I disagree. Both *einkreisen* and *in die Zange nehmen* have the semantic aspect of *restricting/denying the movementof the target*, however *einkreisen* implies - as it's right there in the word - positioning all around the target. *Einkreisen* also has a more *passive* quality to it, while *In die Zange nehmen* usually is used in an *active*/*offensive* situation, *two units restricting movement of the target by actively engaging / closing in on it from different sides*

Comment: @Konadi I forgive you. Just kidding. Thanks for the instruction. Actually I didn't even know the meaning and looked it in the dictionary.